# 'EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.' after upgrade nuxt 2 to nuxt bridge

Tags: nuxt.js, upgrade, mime-types, server-sent-events, nuxt-bridge

```
"@nuxt/bridge": "npm:@nuxt/bridge-edge@^3.0.0-27928371.c30fa0f",
```

I use this version of bridge. It seems the default content type for SSE responses in Nuxt.js Bridge has been changed from text/event-stream to text/plain.

By the way, I am not sure that cause by socket.io, I tried:

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection: 'http://localhost:3000',
  transports: ['polling'],
  polling: {
    extraHeaders: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    },
  },
}));
```

It was not helpful.

Anyone know how to fix it?

The error showing on the console, so far seems not affect any component. I hope it can be fixed. Thanks！